# Making Package in Proteus

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, proteus

How can I correctly dimension a component, as I'd like to create a package on Proteus ARES?
To be specific, I am not sure which measurements and numbers I have to take, when it comes to the pads.
Kindly, find an example photo attached.[image: Mechanical Data for TPA6132A2]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide I found useful when creating a package in Proteus for the Arduino Nano. Hope it helps.

http://www.help2educate.com/make-footprint-in-ares-proteus/

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as making a package in *any* PCB software.

The things you want are the dimensions of the pads and the spacing between them. First, make sure whether they are specifying mm or in. It will usually tell you somewhere near the drawings.

So, first find the length and width of the pads. On your example, these values are given in the circle underneath the left hand drawing. Pad width is 0.28 and the length is 0.85.

So, in Proteus ARES, go to the PCB layout and on the left hand side, you can select one of the SMT pads (whichever best suits your shape/style). This will then give you a list of available shapes and dimensions. Right click somewhere and select 'create' to create a new pad. You will be shown this:
[image]

Give your new pad a name and select the style that best suits it. For your application, a square SMT pad will do. Then click OK.

You will then be faced with this page:
[image]

Simply fill in the details. Change the dimensions as you please. Type 'mm' after the number if you want the dimensions in mm, type 'in' if you want inches and 'th' for thou.

Once you have the dimensions you want, click OK. You can then select it from the list and place it somewhere. Now, right click on the pad, then click replicate. Here you can add more pads along the 'x' or 'y' axis. For example, your given IC has 0.5mm gap from pad center to pad center. If I want 4 in a row on the 'x' axis, I would type '0.5mm' in the 'X-Step' then '3' in number of copies (as I only want 3 more to total 4) as shown here:
[image]

Then click OK. You will now have 4 pads along the 'x' axis with a 0.5mm gap from pad center to pad center:
[image]

Now you do the same for the 'y' axis, and if you want, add some silk screen around the part, by selecting the 2D graphics box and changing your layer to top silk:

[image]

Now just highlight the part, right click and select 'Make Package'. Fill in the details and off you go!